# How to get a 64-bit random value in Delphi?

Tags: delphi, random, delphi-2006

How can I create a random 64-bit integer value in Delphi 2006? The built-in integer-based Random() function seems to return only values between 0 and 2^31.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can use my [GpRandomGen](http://code.google.com/p/gpdelphiunits/source/browse/trunk/src/GpRandomGen.pas?r=21). It implements Marsaglia/Zaman/James algorithm, is extremely fast and supposedly very random. Released as a freeware.

Comment: Seems like a full-featured random number generator although I would prefer a solution using native Delphi functions. The "this is the best known random number generator" statement on top of the file looks a bit too self-confident :-)

Comment: Maybe it was the best in 2002. I have no idea what is the state of the art in random generation nowadays.

Comment: GpRandomGen `is` native Delphi. It does not rely on COM, .NET, ASM, etc. It contains references to the original published research articles, attribution to the original C implementat, etc. What more do you want?

Comment: @blerontin I don't think there was any over-confidence. @gabr is not referring to his implementation as the best, rather he means that the algorithm (not due to him) was the best known RNG. That seems perfectly reasonable to me

Comment: Actually that text ("best random generator") came with the algorithm. I merely copied the complete header while converting the source code.

Comment: Since google code is going away maybe it's time to update link to a new non-google-code source.

Answer (score 10):

Generate two 32 bit randoms and splice them together.

**EDIT**

Similar to @Andreas's answer I like the following (equivalent) implementation:

```
function Random64: UInt64;
var
  Overlay: packed record
    a, b: UInt32;
  end absolute Result;
begin
  Assert(SizeOf(Overlay)=SizeOf(Result));
  Overlay.a := Random32;
  Overlay.b := Random32;
end;
```

Comment: +1. Why make it more complicated than necessary? (Blerotin said "It's for creating unique file names.")

Comment: You could use Int64Rec declared in SysUtils casting Result to it, non need to declare another structure: Int64Rec(Result).Hi := Random32; Int64Rec(Result).Lo := Random32;

Comment: @Idsandon, yes that would probably be even better!

Answer (score 4):

You can generate 64 random bits and interpret the result as an integer. (63 bits if you are working with signed integers and want the result to be non-negative.) Equivalently you can take two random integers in the range 0..2^31-1, plus two extra random bits, and concatenate them to get a random 64-bit integer.

**EDIT:** I was curious about the statistical properties of pseudo-random numbers generated by concatenating pseudo-random components and found that (apparently) this approach might not work well depending on your pseudo-random generator (of course for true random number generation, as from atmospheric noise, concatenating random bits is no problem). For recreational use, the loss of various statistical properties might be acceptable, but for more serious use you might end up needing a custom pseudo-random generator as @gabr suggested. Here is a related question: [Best method of generating a number with 256 random bits?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/565618/best-method-of-generating-a-number-with-256-random-bits/565668#565668)

Answer (score 4):

To answer my own question I came up with the following code:

```
function GetRandomInt64() : int64;
begin
   Int64Rec(result).Words[0] := Random(High(Word));
   Int64Rec(result).Words[1] := Random(High(Word));
   Int64Rec(result).Words[2] := Random(High(Word));
   Int64Rec(result).Words[3] := Random(High(Word));
end;
```

Not sure if this is a valid solution or it will always create the same follow-up number X+1 after a given result number X.

Comment: It depends on what you're using it for. This may be adequate for a simple source of randomness in a game or simulation. If it's for anything related to encryption, stay away from custom, ad-hoc solutions. Every programmer eventually comes up with the idea of combining random sources to create large random numbers. It's a very bad idea in general.

Comment: It's for creating unique file names. Needs not to be encryption-safe.

Comment: @Ferruccio: Out of interest, what's wrong with blerontins suggestion? How can it be exploited? If I needed a 64-bit random number, and only had a 32-bit generator, I would probably just concatenate and believe it was safe. Why isn't it?

Comment: You're doing this for file names? Why do you need 64-bit numbers for that? Are you really creating more than 2 billion files?

Comment: @blerontin Why don't you use the Windows API to get temporary file names?

Comment: @Svein. I don't know how it can be exploited. That's the problem. Like most engineers, I'm not qualified to do that sort of cryptographic analysis. It's probably fine for generating unique file names as long as you have a way to deal with collisions. I suspect that taking the high bits from four random numbers and combining them will tend to decrease the periodicity of your rng.

Comment: 2 Ferruccio, Svein Bringsli: it is not even random, but merely 4 adjacent values from `Random(High(Word))` sequence packed together. Linear congruent generator is deterministic! Also, never returns `FFFF FFFF FFFF FFFF`

Comment: If using if for a filename why not use a guid as a base?

Comment: @David: +1 (isn't there a shell api that returns a unique filename?)

Comment: @Remko Indeed there is, it's called GetTempFileName: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa364991%28VS.85%29.aspx and in my view it is the canonical solution to this problem

Comment: @David: Just wanted you to mention it :D

Answer (score 4):

Create a GUID (eg [CoCreateGuid](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms688568%28VS.85%29.aspx)) and cast it to Int64.

Comment: Or use some crypto hash function on a GUID. :-)

Answer (score 3):

Simple:

```
function Random64: UInt64;
begin
  PCardinal(@result)^ := Random32;
  PCardinal(cardinal(@result) + 4)^ := Random32;
end;
```

where `Random32` is your favourite 32-bit unsigned integer random number function.

Comment: Why the ugly pointer manipulation when there are cleaner way to work on the bytes making up a 64 bit value? Let the compiler calculate offsets! :)

Comment: @Idsandon: The code above most accurately captures the way I *think* about the problem.

Comment: +1 does the job, although Idsandon is right that Int64Rec is cleaner

Comment: +1 for Pointers, I love pointers :D 
-1 for the downvoter not leaving a reason

Comment: @ldsandon: yes sizeof would be better especially if we ever get Delphi x64 (if...)